# Есть ли максимальная разница в датах допустимая в запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle

Работаю над запросом, который ищет строки в таблице, где дата `last_run` + `frequency` (в минутах), больше, чем текущая дата. Заметил, что, похоже, существует верхняя граница для сравнения дат, которую БД может понять.

Например, этот запрос:

```
with tests as (
    select 'TEST 1'  as code, 99999999 as frequency, sysdate as last_run
    from dual union all
    select 'TEST 2'  as code, 99999999999 as frequency, sysdate as last_run
    from dual)
select p.*, (p.last_run + p.frequency / 24 / 60) as next_run
from tests p
where (p.last_run + p.frequency / 24 / 60 < sysdate or p.last_run is null)
```

Ожидаю, что этот запрос ничего не вернет, но вместо этого он возвращает:

| CODE | FREQUENCY | LAST_RUN | NEXT_RUN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 2 | 99999999999 | 05-OCT-2021 10:15:46 AM | 15-APR-4455 08:54:46 PM |

Кажется странным, что БД не может распознать, что год **4455 > 2021**.

Есть ли какая-то максимально возможная разница в датах, которая мне неизвестна?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Is There a Maximum Date Difference Oracle Can Interpret](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69452221) от участника [@Peter Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9213725/peter-sanders)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69452221

Answer (score 3):

> Кажется странным, что БД не может распознать, что год 4455 > 2021.

Может распознать. Дело в том, что год не **4455**, а **-4455**. [См. db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b2ce0a6b2ce23ca4abf766e29585187), показывающий результат с форматом по умолчанию `DD-MON-RR`, с форматом как в вопросе, и форматом ISO с включенным знаком года (первая S в шаблоне формата).

| CODE | FREQUENCY | LAST_RUN | NEXT_RUN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST 2 | 99999999999 | 2021-10-05 17:16:21 | -4454-03-12 03:55:21 |

Значением 99.999.999.999, которое добавляется к текущей дате, составляет 69444444 дня, что приблизительно 190128 лет. Очевидно, что это значительно превышает максимальную дату 9999-12-31. И действительно, при другом значении, например 9.999.999.999 (одну цифру меньше), которое составляет 6944444 дня или приблизительно 19012 лет, будет ошибка [см. db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b2ce0a6b2ce23ca4abf766e29585187).

Проблема, по-видимому, заключается в том, как БД манипулирует своим [внутренним представлением даты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/266304) при выполнении вычислений. При добавлении большого значения, думаю, что год - который хранится в двух байтах, переполняется и начинается отсчёт заново.

Используя тип даты 13, 190128+2021 = 192149, что составляет (256 * 750) + 149. 750 не помещается в один байт, поэтому получается деление с остатком, которое равно 238. Таким образом, первые два байта вычисленной даты будут равны 149,238. Это фактически соответствует году -4459:

```
select dump(date '-4459-01-01') from dual;

Typ=13 Len=8: 149,238,1,1,0,0,0,0
```

Достаточно, чтобы убедится, что именно так и происходит учитывая, что вычисления выходят за пределы ожидаемого диапазона и, вероятно, ещё там выполняются недействительные вычисления високосного года. Суть, однако, в том, что это "развернутое" значение представляет собой действительный год во внутренней нотации.

Те же расчёты с меньшим значением 19012+2021 = 20133, что составляет (256 * 82) + 41. Теперь переполнения нет, поэтому первые два байта вычисленной даты получаются как 41,82. Теперь это не действительный год, поэтому и происходит исключение `ORA-01841`.

Следовательно, необходимо ограничить значение числом, которое никогда не выйдет за пределы 9999-12-31, или проверить его во время выполнения на 9999-12-31 минус текущая дата, если оно слишком большое, проигнорировать его.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69454509) от участника [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)</sub>